# RegEx match from a multi line to end of string buffer and replace with ""

Tags: java, regex

I have the following file contents and I'm trying to match a reg explained below and replace up to the start of the match ("On....wrote") to the end of the string buffer with blank "":

```
-- file.txt (Before regx match and replace) -- 
test

On blah

more blah wrote:

So, this should be stripped all out and all that left should be the above test contents.
-- EOF -- 


-- file.txt (After regex mach and replace) -- 
test
-- EOF --
```

If I read the file contents from above to a String and try to match the "On...wrote:" part I can't seem to replace up to the end of the file from "On ... wrote:"...:

```
    // String text = <file contents from above...the Before contents>
    Pattern PATTERN = 
      Pattern.compile("^(On\\s(.+)wrote:)$", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL );
    Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) {
       // This matches but I want to strip from "On....wrote:  -> <end of string>
       text = m.replaceAll("");  // This should only contain "test"

    }
```

Comment: No, only keep what is before "On ... wrote:". Essentially I want to remove "On ... wrote:....<end of string>".  Only thing left should be "test" which is the only text before "On ... wrote:" pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do a match, you can directly replace. If the pattern used in replace doesn't match anything then nothing will happen.

Try the following:

```
// String text = <file contents from above...the Before contents>
String text = text.replaceAll("^(On.*?wrote:).*$", "");
```

**NOTE:** You might need to turn the flags for `Pattern.MULTILINE` and `Pattern.DOTALL` from inside the regex, you can do it like this:

```
String text = text.replaceAll("(?sm)^(On.*?wrote:).*$", "");
```

**EDIT:** Of course you can:

```
// String text = <file contents from above...the Before contents>
Pattern PATTERN = 
  Pattern.compile("^(On.*?wrote:).*$", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL );
Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(text);
if (m.find()) {
   text = m.replaceAll("");  // This should only contain "test"

}
```

Comment: Ah, beautiful! Thanks for the info! Very concise! Worked great!

Comment: qq: is there any way to define a Pattern variable Pattern PATTERN (like I have above) to replace the regex itself?  there is a requirement to first match and determine the pattern first and I already have that defined in variable so was wondering if I could reuse that Pattern variable that contains the regex?